# VB.net insert into multiple related tables using a stored procedure. Only first table receives an inserted row

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, stored-procedures, sqldataadapter, insert-into

The stored procedure ins_address works if used stand-alone, no errors.
When using the VB code (shown below), a row does not get inserted into tbl_AddressEntity. tbl_Address does, it's fine. I have racked my brains for nearly two whole days and I'm ready to jump off a cliff. Can anyone advise why the row won't insert into the second table? Thank you.

`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ins_address]
@AddressLine1 AS VARCHAR(60),
@AddressLine2 AS VARCHAR(60),
@AddressLine3 AS VARCHAR(60),
@TownText AS VARCHAR(30),
@CountyText AS VARCHAR(30),
@PostcodeTownDistrictID AS INT,
@PostcodeOutwardCode AS VARCHAR(4),
@PostcodeInwardCode AS VARCHAR(3),
@SiteID AS INT,
@CompanyBranchID AS INT,
@PersonID AS INT,
@AddressTypeID AS INT,
@AddressID AS INT = -1 OUTPUT

AS 

BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO tbl_Address 
(
AddressLine1, 
AddressLine2, 
AddressLine3, 
TownText, 
CountyText,
PostcodeTownDistrictID,
PostcodeOutwardCode,
PostcodeInwardCode
)
VALUES 
(
@AddressLine1, 
@AddressLine2, 
@AddressLine3, 
@TownText, 
@CountyText,
@PostcodeTownDistrictID,
@PostcodeOutwardCode,
@PostcodeInwardCode
);

RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY();

SELECT @AddressID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO tbl_AddressEntity
(
AddressID,
SiteID,
CompanyBranchID,
PersonID,
AddressTypeID
)
VALUES
(
@AddressID,
@SiteID,
@CompanyBranchID,
@PersonID,
@AddressTypeID
);

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 DECLARE
        @ErrorMessage nvarchar(2048)
        ,@ErrorSeverity int
        ,@ErrorState int

    SELECT
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ,@ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        ,@ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0

    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);

END CATCH
```

`

---

```
`

Private Sub UBSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UBSave.Click
          Try

                    If Not formOptions(0).Contains("Company Customer") Then
                        'Force commit of data changes to DS
                        **Me.UGAddresses.UpdateData()**
                        Me.UGContactInformation.UpdateData()

                        'Merge text boxes into DS
                        getNonCompanyCustomerFields()

                        'Save the contact first!
                        kernel.updateContact(Me.DsContact1)

                        'Now assuming we have the PKID from the contact insert, update associations to match!
                        If formOptions(0).Contains("New") Then
                            For Each row As DataRow In DsAddress1.Tables(0).Rows
                                If row.RowState = DataRowState.Added Then
                                    If row.Item("PersonID") Is System.DBNull.Value Then
                                        row.Item("PersonID") = DsContact1.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("PersonID")
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Next
                            For Each row As DataRow In DsContactInfo1.Tables(0).Rows
                                If row.RowState = DataRowState.Added Then
                                    If row.Item("PersonID") Is System.DBNull.Value Then
                                        row.Item("PersonID") = DsContact1.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("PersonID")
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Next
                            If Me.UTCMain.Tabs("Customer").Visible Then
                                Me.DsCustomers1.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("PersonID") = DsContact1.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("PersonID")
                            End If
                        End If

                        **kernel.updateAddresses(Me.DsAddress1)**
                        kernel.updateContactInfo(Me.DsContactInfo1)
                        If Me.UTCMain.Tabs("PersonCustomer").Visible Then
                            kernel.updateCustomer(Me.DsCustomers1)
                        End If
                        Me.Text = Me.Text.Replace(" *", "")

                        'Company Customer
                    Else
                        getCompanyCustomerFields()
                        kernel.updateCustomer(Me.DsCustomers1)
                        Me.Text = Me.Text.Replace(" *", "")
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Exception thrown during save : " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
                    mySharedFunctions.LogProgress("frmContact.UBSave_Click - Error : " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
                    If Not ex.InnerException Is Nothing Then
                        mySharedFunctions.LogProgress("Inner exception : " & ex.InnerException.Message)
                    End If
                End Try
        End Sub
```

`

---

The data adapter update procedure:
`

```
Public Sub updateAddresses(ByRef dsTemp As dsAddress)

            'For inserts we're passing back the new PKID amd syncing with the dataset via the source column mapping on the insert command. 
            'So we should be able to update by ref.
            Me.SqlDaAddress.Update(dsTemp)
        End Sub
```

`

---

DsAddress1 dataset contains one table, containing results from this select statement in the relevant stored procedure:
`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_address_by_companybranch_or_person]
/*@SiteID AS INT = -1,*/
@CompanyBranchID AS INT = -1,
@PersonID AS INT = -1

AS

IF @CompanyBranchID != -1
BEGIN

    SELECT     dbo.tbl_Address.AddressID, dbo.tbl_Address.AddressLine1, dbo.tbl_Address.AddressLine2, dbo.tbl_Address.AddressLine3, 
                      dbo.tbl_Address.TownText, dbo.tbl_Address.CountyText, dbo.tbl_Address.PostcodeTownDistrictID, dbo.tbl_Address.PostcodeOutwardCode, 
                      dbo.tbl_Address.PostcodeInwardCode, dbo.tbl_AddressEntity.SiteID, dbo.tbl_AddressEntity.CompanyBranchID, dbo.tbl_AddressEntity.PersonID, 
                      dbo.tbl_AddressEntity.AddressTypeID
    FROM         dbo.tbl_Address INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_AddressEntity ON dbo.tbl_Address.AddressID = dbo.tbl_AddressEntity.AddressID
    WHERE     CompanyBranchID = @CompanyBranchID

END
ELSE

BEGIN

    SELECT     dbo.tbl_Address.AddressID, dbo.tbl_Address.AddressLine1, dbo.tbl_Address.AddressLine2, dbo.tbl_Address.AddressLine3, 
                      dbo.tbl_Address.TownText, dbo.tbl_Address.CountyText, dbo.tbl_Address.PostcodeTownDistrictID, dbo.tbl_Address.PostcodeOutwardCode, 
                      dbo.tbl_Address.PostcodeInwardCode, dbo.tbl_AddressEntity.SiteID, dbo.tbl_AddressEntity.CompanyBranchID, dbo.tbl_AddressEntity.PersonID, 
                      dbo.tbl_AddressEntity.AddressTypeID
    FROM         dbo.tbl_Address INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbl_AddressEntity ON dbo.tbl_Address.AddressID = dbo.tbl_AddressEntity.AddressID 
    WHERE   PersonID = @PersonID


END
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why this line?

```
RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

You exit from your stored proc at this point without executing the remaining code.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) says

```
Exits unconditionally from a query or procedure. RETURN is immediate and complete 
and can be used at any point to exit from a procedure, batch, or statement block. 
Statements that follow RETURN are not executed.
```

... and please, don't jump .... :-)

Comment: Gah! I had no idea! I've taken on the database from someone else and had to adjust a lot of stored procedures and code. Thank you for your help. I guess that explains why tbl_AddressEntity receives no row! :-)